# How can I get C-c C-n to format the current line in proof-general coq-mode-map

Tags: emacs, coq, proof-general

I'm using proof-general to write Coq proofs.

When I use `C-c C-n` in a proof, my cursor is moved to the next line, but the current line is not formatted. So for instance, if I type:

```
intros n. <C-c C-n>
```

my cursor moves to the next line, but `intros n.` remains unindented. So I have to go back up a line, go to the end of the line and hit `<RET>` to auto-indent the coq statement. At which point, `proof-general` considers that statement changed and I have to re-run it.

Ideally, I would line `C-c C-n` to auto-indent the line it is running and to not go to the next line.

How can I make that happen?

Comment: Hi @azani, your question/suggestion makes a lot of sense. I've opened an [issue in the ProofGeneral bug tracker](https://github.com/ProofGeneral/PG/issues/603) and I'll try to have a look soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're describing using advice:

```
(advice-add 'proof-assert-next-command-interactive :before
            (lambda (&rest args) (indent-for-tab-command)))
```

… but I suspect this is an AB problem: `C-c C-n` doesn't insert a newline, so if you're writing proofs you will in fact press `RET` roughly once per time you press `C-c C-n`.  If you press it *before* pressing `C-c C-n`, then the line will be properly indented.

Worse, you shouldn't typically have an incorrectly indented `intros` in the first place, if you're using the default setup (electric-indent): whichever parent line is causing `intros` to need indentation should also cause it to *be* indented when its line is created.

If I misunderstood, please do update the OP with a concrete example of the scenario that leads you to needing this feature, and we can see whether there is already something in PG that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I was also thinking about `advice-add` as suggested by @Clément, but actually I believe the OP's suggestion is rather a bug-fix than a feature wish…:

When we type `C-c C-n` just before adding a newline with `RET`, if the line is not already properly indented (which can occur if this line was edited **not after typing `RET` previously on the line before**, which can occur in practice), the `C-c C-n` action is distractedly removed… so we need to redo `C-c C-n` anew.

So I've just opened a tentative PR in https://github.com/ProofGeneral/PG/pull/604, @azani and @Clément: feel free to comment/review there when you have some time.